# "Line 2: google is not defined" in Google Earth Engine Code

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to draw a heat map in Google Earth Engine Code using coordinates in the code. But it says "Line 2: google is not defined" when I try to run it. I've tried importing Google into the code, but that results in another error. I've tried searching the docs and assets for a solution but found nothing. What do I do here?

Code in question:

```
var Locations = [
  new google.maps.LatLng(-89.91161093276477, 35.241969778429194),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-89.87947624903887, 35.195319161704404),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-89.81418532101328, 35.17188216058175),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-89.75643652692003, 35.183538628834484),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-89.7496498284386, 35.14509890887518),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-89.78504762327763, 35.063349559432304),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-89.83100682136623, 35.013757847903044),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-89.85342496546569, 35.001086997562474),
];
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Earth Engine Code Editor you can only use the Earth Engine API (and standard JavaScript). Google Earth Engine has its own API and you cannot use Google Maps API items like `google.maps.LatLng`.

I suggest reading [Get Started with Earth Engine](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/getstarted) to learn about how to program with Google Earth Engine and what you can do in the Earth Engine Code Editor environment.